# RegEx Validation Check

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to Regular Expressions, can't wrap my mind around this one, can anyone please help me out here, what is it doing:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9~!@#$%^&amp; *()_<>+`\-={}\[\]:;'&quot;,./?|\\\s']{0,8000}$
```

what possibilities does this left out?

Comment: leaves out a lot, what would you like to accomplish with your regex? what do you want to allow and disallow ?

Comment: @CSᵠ can you be more specific like what? One possibility as Cas mentioned is HTML characters, as I didn't write this but happen to find in our code base written by someone else in the past, therefore, I need to clear my concept before new implementation.

Comment: you can't add "html entities" in a regex character class as it would interpret it character by character (eg. `/[&quot;]/` would match theese characters only: `o`, `q`, `t`, `u`, `&` and `;` !)

Comment: The site only works for Python, javascript ? seems no c# support ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://regex101.com/r/mN3aB2

you tell me what it leaves out

not what you meant? be more clear in what you want to know

**EDIT**

A mate pointed this one out to me

http://regex101.com/r/tS5dT9

Comment: I don't know as I didn't write it

Comment: @Ali on the site in my answer is the explanation of what it doesn't capture.

Comment: @Ali http://regex101.com/r/rZ5bQ0 here with (i think) pretty much all characters (Alt-combinations left out)

Comment: A bit late, but here's some more from my keyboard only (no alt+xxx): http://regex101.com/r/sP3nX9

Comment: @Enissay yeah, thats what i warned Ali for... there are a lot of inputs to forget about very easily.